# Dynamic form generation, advanced behavior

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm constructing a input form generation system. A simplified version of my code looks as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="ele in form.Fields">
    <label for="{{ele.InputId}}">
        {{ele.Label}}
    </label>
    <span ng-if="ele.Type === 'TextBox'">
        <input type="text" id="{{ele.InputId}}" ng-model="ele.Value" />
    </span>
    <span ng-if="ele.Type === 'DropDownList'">
        <select id="{{ele.InputId}}" 
                ng-options="opt.Name as opt.Value for opt in ele.AvailableValues" 
                ng-model="ele.Value">
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

The problem:

I'm attempting to add in functionality where if a certain field contains specific values, other fields react. For example, if a specific field's select contains "Yes", I'd want a specific field to become required. Another example is I'll have a select with a few options, and depending which option is selected, specific fields become visible, while others become hidden.

My form.Fields is generated server side, it contains all field inputs for the form, and the forms generate correctly. Each field object contains enough information to determine my reaction conditions, but I am stuck trying to figure out how to make angular to react off my desired conditions and rules.

Should I dynamically add a ng-changed() attribute to inputs? How would I dynamically add them in? Or is better to setup dynamic $watch/$observe (if even possible)? If I can get angular to trigger correctly, modifying the field array to show/hide/make things required will be a breeze

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click functions to set scope values that are associated to the required attributes of your form fields.